# Android Compose unknown crash

Tags: android, crash, android-compose

I've got this weird crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
You must call layoutWithConstraints first

androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.MultiParagraphLayoutCache.getTextLayoutResult (MultiParagraphLayoutCache.kt:118)
androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.TextAnnotatedStringNode.draw (TextAnnotatedStringNode.kt:489)
androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawDirect-x_KDEd0$ui_release (LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:105)
androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release (LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:86)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers (NodeCoordinator.kt:365)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw (NodeCoordinator.kt:354)
androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw (LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:182)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers (NodeCoordinator.kt:362)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers (NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke (NodeCoordinator.kt:384)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke (NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe (Snapshot.kt:2303)
androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe (SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473)
androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads (SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release (OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke (NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke (NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record (RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:209)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList (RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:304)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw (AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1167)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:22957)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:21789)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4606)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4579)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:21740)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4606)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4579)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:21740)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4606)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4579)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:21740)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4606)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4579)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:21740)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:561)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:567)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:673)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3749)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2428)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9437)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1228)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:1012)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:922)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1213)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:334)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8513)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:582)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I changed "Text" component to "BasicText" component. Also I was using the compose components (`androidx.compose.ui:ui`, `androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling`, `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation`) version 1.5.0, but one of my libraries used version 1.6.0-alpha03 so it was overriding my used version 1.5.0. So I had to add these dependencies with version 1.6.0-alpha04 to override the bugged version 1.6.0-alpha03.
>
> I added these dependencies:
>
> ```
> implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.0-alpha04'
> implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.6.0-alpha04'
> implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
> implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.0-alpha04'
> ```
>
> When changing to BasicText, I still had the crash happening, but when adding these dependencies with version 1.6.0-alpha04, the crash stopped happening. So make both changes to eliminate the crash.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [bug in the 1.6.0 Alpha libraries](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295214720) effecting `Text` Composables in `material3`.

A workaround is to use the `BasicText` composable or downgrade to the stable Compose version `1.5.0`.

In my case I found a dependency that was forcing the use of 1.6 Alpha libraries, after downgrading that dependency the issue was fixed.

You can check your dependency graph for any dependency that forces the alpha version of Compose, using `./gradlew -q dependencies`

Comment: I already use androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00, which use Compose version 1.5.0..
What do I need to change specifically?

Comment: You should check your dependency graph for any dependency that forces the alpha version of Compose. you can use `./gradlew -q dependencies` . I Will also edit my answer

Comment: I have both 1.6.0-alpha03 implemented from other dependency. how can I force it to use version 1.5.0 ?

Comment: I tried something and uploaded a version, will update if issue keeps happening.

Comment: You will have to use a version of that other dependency that uses version 1.5.0, otherwise it will force the use of the alpha version.

Comment: Downgrading to version 1.5.0 is not an option because other dependencies are using version 1.6.0-alpha03. Do you have any other way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, like I wrote in my answer, you can use BasicText instead of Text.